# Fetch chat messages in Background

Tags: android, firebase, android-service

This code is running while the App is in foreground and Building Notification for any new messages. But I want to implement the notification for the new chat message while My Application is in the background. So according to me, It will happen when I use 'Services' to run it in the background, but I am confused about to implement it. Any idea or advice how to implement it.

```
package com.gyaanify.groups.campfire;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import static android.R.id.message;

public class chat extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    String domain;
    String name;
    String name_desig;
    String desig;
    String mesg;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        domain = getIntent().getStringExtra("domain");
        name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        desig = getIntent().getStringExtra("desig");

        name_desig = name + " [" + desig + "]";

        displayChatMessages();

        FloatingActionButton fab =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
                                       mesg = input.getText().toString();
                                       getmsg();

                                       // Read the input field and push a new instance
                                       // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                                       FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                               .getReference(domain)
                                               .push()
                                               .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(), name_desig));

                                       // Clear the input


                                       input.setText("");
                                   }
                               }
        );

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public String getmsg() {

        return mesg;


    }

    private void displayChatMessages() {

        ListView listOfMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
                R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(domain)) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);


                String abc = messageText.getNotification().getBody();

                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                        .setContentText(abc)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


                TextView messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                // Set their text
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

                // Format the date before showing it
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("chat Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly the confusion about to implementation you have?

Comment: how to transfer this activity to background service. An overview will help me to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, extend your class with Service or IntentService, according to your requirement. Make changes in AndroidManifest.xml file, for example, you have a class name MyApp then,

```
<service 
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:exported="false">            
</service>
```

Then you can start your service by using intent:

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyApp.class));
```

And stop your service:

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyApp.class));
```

Comment: Does this service needs to be included inside the same activity tag or outside it because writing it outside giving me error that .chat is not assignable to service. Thanks a lot, brother.

Comment: @Sumiet You have to include it inside application tag, not inside some activity tag. It's giving that error because you didn't extend your class with Service.

Comment: @Sumiet if you find my answer helpful please accept it or upvote it. Thanks :)

Comment: My chat class is already extending AppCompactActivity.  As java does not support multiple inheritance, how do I extend it with service. Sorry , for these types of basic question. I just got started with android.

Comment: @Sumiet You need to create different class and move methods which you want to run in background in that class.

Comment: I can call any function to fetch chat from this activity and put it in notification Builder in the Background Service which i want to run. Is this a Right way of doing. Thanks for your Reply

Comment: @Sumiet yea, you can do that too.

Comment: @Dhruv Thanks for replying. However, I want notification to be built only when chat is in background (obviously, like other chat apps). Can you please add an answer to this or post a link to any tutorial. I'm bit new to this.

Comment: @Sumiet are you using FCM or GCM for push notification? And who is doing backend work?

Comment: Sir, I am using FCM for notification

Comment: @Sumiet Please, Don't need to call me sir. Firebase provides you with two services named MyFcmListenerService and MyInstanceIDListenerService respectively. Did you copy that in your project? They will handle it on their end, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Basically, I used two services for the token generation and sending messages to the Firebase database . But I want my chat activity to run it in background to notify me when new messages arrived.